# Divide pivot table data by an arbitrary column in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, pivot-table

I have this data from a **pivot table**:

```
Countries   P1  P2  Total
Country 1   10      69
Country 2   36  2   92
Country 3   21  24  100
Country 4   22      77
Country 5   13      79
Country 6   12  1   48
Country 7   14      29
Country 8   22  1   46
Country 9   4   1   31
Country 10  16  7   120
Country 11  25  2   114
Country 12  8   11  68
Country 13  5       27
Country 14  11  3   23
Country 15  6       19
Country 16  33      79
```

Where:

- 1st column is the country name
- 2nd and 3rd column are the tickets introduced in the system
- 4th column is the total (disregard the data - total is not accurate)

Additionally, I have another table that looks like this:

```
Country P1  P2
Country 1   2   3
Country 2   2   2
Country 3   0   2
Country 4   0   3
Country 5   1   1
Country 6   2   2
Country 7   1   2
Country 8   3   3
Country 9   1   4
Country 10  2   1
Country 11  4   2
Country 12  2   1
Country 13  3   2
Country 14  3   3
Country 15  1   2
Country 16  2   2
```

Where the data represents the number of users of the application in each country.

I want to be able to show the number of tickets submitted divided by the number of users in each country. Any ideeas how to do that?

Thank you very much,

Razvan

Answer (score 0):

I've done vlookups in columns beside the pivot table to pull in the values you need from the 2nd cell range.  If you need this automated some simple VBA to refresh the pivot table and then re-generate the required formula.